# BlueHost - Run Rails Application without port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bluehost, puma

currently I just deploy my Ruby on Rails application into BlueHost. Application is running well when I run `rails s` or `puma`, but these commands make my application run on `www.mydomain.com:3000` instead `www.mydomain.com`. I think to run without port I can use `rails s -p 80` or `puma -p 80`, but I got this notification :

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/gems/puma-2.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:195:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 80 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/gems/puma-2.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:195:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/gems/puma-2.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:195:in `add_tcp_listener'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/gems/puma-2.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:96:in `block in parse'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/gems/puma-2.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:82:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/gems/puma-2.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:82:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/gems/puma-2.8.2/lib/puma/runner.rb:119:in `load_and_bind'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/gems/puma-2.8.2/lib/puma/single.rb:73:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/gems/puma-2.8.2/lib/puma/cli.rb:499:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/gems/puma-2.8.2/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/bin/puma:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@ukm/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I try to check with `lsof -i :80` and this is the response :

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   11983   root    5u  IPv4 6278784      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   11983   root    6u  IPv6 6278786      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   11984 nobody    5u  IPv4 6278784      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   11984 nobody    6u  IPv6 6278786      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   11985 nobody    5u  IPv4 6278784      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   11985 nobody    6u  IPv6 6278786      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   11986 nobody    5u  IPv4 6278784      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   11986 nobody    6u  IPv6 6278786      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   11987 nobody    5u  IPv4 6278784      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   11987 nobody    6u  IPv6 6278786      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14872   root    5u  IPv4 6278784      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14872   root    6u  IPv6 6278786      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I use `service httpd stop` to stop apache server that running on my main domain.

Thank you guys.